# MySQLWorkbench recreating indexes with every table change

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Why does MySQLWorkbench suggest I drop and recreate indexes with every table change?

Do the indexes need to be recreated with every table change, even if I add new (non-indexed) fields?